# Prodution ready themeSelector for Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, themes

I need to create a Shiny App that has a light and dark theme, which the users can pick inside the UI. On RStudio's site a page details [themes](https://rstudio.github.io/shinythemes/) and the themeSelector(), but it states "The theme selector is only meant to be used while developing an application." Are there any librarys which allow dynamically changing themes that are production ready?

Comment: Can't you let the themeSelector on a deployed app ? I think it helps to choose a theme, but you can let it on your app even when dev is done.

Comment: I don't really want the users to chose any theme.  I just want the users to have an option to select a dark or a light theme.  I plan on modifying GyD selectInput control into an actionButton that will choose between two themes probably cosmo and darkly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may only meant to be used while developing, but I don't see any reason why you couldn't use it in production. If you take a look at the [code](https://github.com/rstudio/shinythemes/blob/master/R/shinytheme.R), all it does is looking up and changing the `stylesheet link` in the `head` section.

There is no other way of achieving this than using `javaScript`, so I would just go ahead and use what's already written.

You could modify the `themeSelector` function to change from a draggable fixed panel to a simple `selectInput` like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

themeSelector <- function() {
    div(
      div(
        selectInput("shinytheme-selector", "Choose a theme",
                    c("default", shinythemes:::allThemes()),
                    selectize = FALSE
        )
      ),
      tags$script(
        "$('#shinytheme-selector')
        .on('change', function(el) {
        var allThemes = $(this).find('option').map(function() {
        if ($(this).val() === 'default')
        return 'bootstrap';
        else
        return $(this).val();
        });
        // Find the current theme
        var curTheme = el.target.value;
        if (curTheme === 'default') {
        curTheme = 'bootstrap';
        curThemePath = 'shared/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css';
        } else {
        curThemePath = 'shinythemes/css/' + curTheme + '.min.css';
        }
        // Find the <link> element with that has the bootstrap.css
        var $link = $('link').filter(function() {
        var theme = $(this).attr('href');
        theme = theme.replace(/^.*\\//, '').replace(/(\\.min)?\\.css$/, '');
        return $.inArray(theme, allThemes) !== -1;
        });
        // Set it to the correct path
        $link.attr('href', curThemePath);
        });"
      )
    )
  }

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(4, themeSelector())
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I dropped your code into my application and it worked perfectly. I still need to integrate your code into my final application, but I couldn't be happier your solution.